# Running selenium bash script from an osx daemon

Tags: linux, macos, selenium, daemon

I have created a bash file that will kick off testing my website in Safari using selenium. I would like to have to instance occur every night at 5:55pm. To do so I have created a daemon in in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons. For some reason I never see the bash script start my selenium code. I'm wondering if anyone has had any experience with this? When I run my selenium bash script safari will open and my automated tests will run fine. I'm just a little confused why the same thing is not happening when calling the bash script from a daemon. I have already started the daemon using launchctl.

**runselenium.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">;
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.runselenium.daemon</string>

        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>bash</string>
                <string>/Users/admin/Desktop/workspace/runSelenium.bash</string>
        </array>

        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
                <key>Hour</key>
                <integer>17</integer>
                <key>Minute</key>
                <integer>55</integer>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**runSelenium.bash**

```
#!/bin/bash

source /Users/admin/Desktop/workspace/set-selenium-classpath.bash

java  selenium.Main
```

*The current error I am seeing in the console is com.apple.launchd: (com.runselenium.daemon[479]) Exited with code: 1*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deamon does not use your environment settings, specifically your user PATH. Make sure your script explicitly defines everything: PATH (or use only global paths), variables, etc. If this does not work, post your script and any errors.

Comment: I posted the bash file above. Within the bash file runSelenium I call another bash file that I have set up to to define the classpath. The current erro I am seeing in the console is com.apple.launchd: (com.runselenium.daemon[479]) Exited with code: 1

Comment: Like I said: you do not know what the current environment is. How do you know where `./` will be? Set everything explicitly, or use global paths on everything. Add extra echo messages into your scripts to see what is happening.

Comment: I've updated the bash script and I'm still getting the same problem. I'm going to assume it's the java program call. Any idea how to specify the full file path of when Main is?

Comment: `java <package.name>.<class.name>`?